# Can't login on a website with Webservice and PHP

Tags: php, web-services

I have access to the webservice of an website which allow you to get a user information if you know his username and security code. I tried to do this with a simple test, but I always recieve the message "unknown username or wrong security-code", although the information is correct. 
Any idea what is wrong with this code?

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('http://handballmania.tk/fx/WebService.wsdl');
$Username = 'icsulescu';
$SecurityCode = 'nusa7maru';
try {
    $answer = $client->GetTeam($Username, $SecurityCode);
} 
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the parameters sent should be contained in an array.

```
...
$user_info["Username"] = "icsulescu";
$user_info["SecurityCode"] = "nusa7maru";
...
$answer = $client->GetTeam($user_info);
...
```

Comment: I don't think so. I used print_r($client->__getFunctions()); to see the function structure and it looks like this: Array ( [0] => HaMaResponse GetTeam(string $Username, string $SecurityCode) ).

Comment: Oh well. Just trying to help.

Comment: I understand and thanks for the help. I'll try to contact the admin of the website. It could be an error from his code ...